# How to remove stopwords from a vector of sentences?

Tags: c++, text

I am working on some code that requires stopwords to be removed from sentences. My current solution does not work.

I have a vector of two test sentences:
`std::vector<std::string> sentences = {"this is a test", "another a test"};`

I have an unordered set of strings containing stopwords:
 `std::unordered_set<std::string> stopwords;`

Now I tried to loop over the sentences in the vector, check and compare each word with the stopwords, and if it is a stopword is should get removed.

```
    sentences.erase(std::remove_if(sentences.begin(), sentences.end(),
        [](const std::string &s){return stopwords.find(s) != stopwords.end();}),
        sentences.end());
```

The idea is that my vector -after removing the stopwords- contains the sentences without the stopwords, but for now, I get the exact same sentences back. Any idea why?

My unordered set is filled with the following function:

```
void load() {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open ("stopwords.txt");
    if(!file.is_open()) {return;}
    std::string stopword;
        while (file >> stopword) {
            stopwords.insert(stopword);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should start with a simple `std::string` (no vector) and try and remove the words from it, since that whole piece is missing from what you're trying to do.  Once you have that working, then expand it to use a vector.  You can't write code to do this for a vector if the foundation of deleting words from a string doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code cannot work, since you are not deleting words from each individual string.  Your `erase/remove_if` call takes an entire string and tries to match the word in the set with the entire string.

First, you should write a simple function that when given a `std::string` and a map of words to delete, return the string with the deleted words.

Here is a small function using `std::istringstream` that can do this:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string remove_stop_words(const std::string& src, const std::unordered_set<std::string>& stops)
{
   std::string retval;
   std::istringstream strm(src);
   std::string word;
   while (strm >> word)
   {
     if ( !stops.count(word) )
        retval += word + " ";
   }
   if ( !retval.empty())
      retval.pop_back();
   return retval;
}

int main()
{
  std::string test = "this is a test";
  std::unordered_set<std::string> stops = {"is", "test"};
  std::cout << "Changed word:\n" << remove_stop_words(test, stops) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
   Changed word:
   this a
```

So once you have this working correctly, the `std::vector` version is nothing more than looping through each item in the vector and calling the `remove_stop_words` function:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> test = {"this is a test", "another a test"};
  std::unordered_set<std::string> stops = {"is", "test"};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i)
      test[i] = remove_stop_words(test[i], stops); 
  std::cout << "Changed words:\n";
  for ( auto& s : test )
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Changed words:
this a
another a
```

Note that you can utilize the `std::transform` function to remove the hand-rolled loop in the above example:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> test = {"this is a test", "another a test"};
  std::unordered_set<std::string> stops = {"is", "test"};

  // Use std::transform
  std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), 
                 [&](const std::string& s){return remove_stop_words(s, stops);});

  std::cout << "Changed words:\n";
  for ( auto& s : test )
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also see now why my previous code didn't work.